# What to use instead of Visual Studio for Applications?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

What is the Microsoft successor to the obsoleted [Visual Studio for Applications (VSA)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974548.aspx) technology, or what is a good alternative?

[Obsoleted API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.jscript.vsa.vsaengine.aspx)

Comment: As far as sources tell, there isn't any.

Answer (score 2):

From what I've seen, the answer is PowerShell - a full .NET powered scripting language, designed for systems administrators (and useful for developers), successor to .cmd and .bat files, and able to be embedded into other systems fairly easily.

Comment: I would agree.  Also, by using the `System.Management.Automation` namespace and the `PowerShell` class, you can actually use PowerShell inside of your own .net application.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the successor was [Visual Studio Tools for Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc175996%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).  Although I'm not sure if that is that is still support.  Version 2.0 was released with Visual Studio 2008 and hasn't been updated since.

Comment: Aren't they different concepts? I'm under the impression VSTA is about integrating an IDE and plugins into your app while VSA is about integrating a scripting engine. Am I misunderstanding the difference?

Comment: VSTA is a superset of VSA, for better or worse.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just using MS Office, you can use Visual Studio Tools for Office.

See here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2tx7z6d.aspx
here:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=20479
and here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh133430